# Superimposing characters in text mode (pdfTeX)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to compose a non-Unicode character by arranging Unicode characters one above the other or one next to the other close-up, but I'd need a negative space which in text mode isn't available. Is there a way to get something similar?

Comment: Why should you not be able to use a `\hspace{-1pt}` in text mode?

Comment: Because by "negative space" I meant `\!`, and I didnt know the argument of `\hspace` could be negative. :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- if that character string happens to fall exactly at the right margin, an `\hspace` can break, unless it's explicitly told not to.  `\kern` won't break.

Comment: Can you tell what characters you want to superimpose to each other?

Comment: @MickG The question is too generic to receive an answer.

Comment: In fact it already _has_ received one: `\hspace` with a negative argument. Anyway my aim was to compose the character for Biang biang noodles (see Wikipedia), which isn't present in Unicode, by mounting together various pieces available in Unicode, combining negative spaces with `\raisebox`es, `\scalebox`es and possibly `\rotatebox`es. I've managed that, so my problem is solved.

Comment: @MickG do you want to self answer (or delete or...) (just to get this off the list of unanswered questions:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer as per David Carlisle's request. The point is that I tend not to invent too much, and I had no idea `\hspace` could accept a negative argument, so I tried `\!` which isn't allowed in text mode since it's defined in terms of `\thinmuskip`. The character I wanted to compose was the Biang in [Biangbiang noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biangbiang_noodles). I ended up doing it like this:

```
%Comandi comuni
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{hyperref,mathptmx}
\newfontfamily{\Cht}{STKaiti}
\newcommand{\scb}{\scalebox}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace}
\newcommand{\zhangmazhang}{\scb{1}[3.33333333333]{長}\hspace{-3pt}\scb{2.3}[3.5385]{馬}\hspace{-3pt}\scb{1}[3.33333333333]{長}}
\newcommand{\niuyanniu}{\scb{1}[2]{幺}\hsp{-4pt}\scb{1.3}[2.1667]{言}\hsp{-4pt}\scb{1}[2]{幺}}
\newcommand{\STKaitibiangbiang}{\scb{8}[10]{辶}\hspace{-57pt}\rotatebox[x=0.2cm,y=1cm]{-7}{\scb{5}[2]{\raisebox{5.3pt}{心}}}\hsp{-37pt}\scb{0.7}[0.7]{\raisebox{33pt}{\zhangmazhang}}\hsp{-28pt}\raisebox{43pt}{\scb{1.25}[1.25]{\niuyanniu}}\hsp{-39pt}\raisebox{26pt}{\scb{1}[4.5]{月}}\hsp{0.87cm}\raisebox{25pt}{\scb{1.2}[4.8]{刂}}\hsp{-1.5cm}\raisebox{61pt}{\scb{3.9}[1.5]{八}}\hsp{-1.7cm}\raisebox{58pt}{\scb{5.6}[4]{宀}}\hsp{0.21cm}}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\Cht{\scb{8}[10]{辶}\hspace{-57pt}\rotatebox[x=0.2cm,y=1cm]{-7}{\scb{5}[2]{\raisebox{5.3pt}{心}}}\hsp{-37pt}\scb{0.7}[0.7]{\raisebox{33pt}{\zhangmazhang}}\hsp{-28pt}\raisebox{43pt}{\scb{1.25}[1.25]{\niuyanniu}}\hsp{-39pt}\raisebox{26pt}{\scb{1}[4.5]{月}}\hsp{0.87cm}\raisebox{25pt}{\scb{1.2}[4.8]{刂}}\hsp{-1.5cm}\raisebox{61pt}{\scb{3.9}[1.5]{八}}\hsp{-1.7cm}\raisebox{58pt}{\scb{5.6}[4]{宀}}\hsp{0.21cm}}}吗\scb{0.1}[0.1]{\STKaitibiangbiang}\scb{0.4}[0.4]{\STKaitibiangbiang}\\[1cm]
Oh yeah! Fatto!
\end{document}
```

Btw yes, `\Cht` is a TeX-style syntax font switch, so `\Cht{…}` should be `{\Cht …}`. I only learnt that long after this was done.